# Find $\int 1/u dx$, where $u$ is polynomial in $x$

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials

> What is
> $$\int \frac{1}{u}dx,$$
> where $u$ is a polynomial in terms of $x$?

Is there any formula to expand it ?

I know that $\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{x} dx = \log|x| + C$

So I think  $\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{u} dx $ should be $\displaystyle\frac{\log|u|}{\frac{du}{dx}} + C$ , but I am not sure.

Comment: Look up integration of *rational functions*

Comment: Try to use Mathjax when you write equations. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: There is a lengthy algorithmic procedure to write down an antiderivative of $\frac 1u$, which is essentially as hard as giving an explicit factorization of the polynomial $u$ over $\Bbb R$ (plus taxes).

Comment: No general formula to expand it comes to mind but as a handy technique you can decompose *$u$* either using long division or partial fraction and subsequently use common integrals such as the one you mentioned in your question to help you try to reduce the difficulty

Comment: If you think $\int\frac{1}{u}dx=\frac{\log|u|}{\frac{du}{dx}}+C$, then you should just be able to differentiate and check. Now, does the differentiation give what you want? use the quotient rule to differentiate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your question is about any general polynomial, I will try to give a general idea. Let us assume you want to calculate
$$\int \frac 1{P(x)}\;\text{d}x$$
where $P(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$.

We will decompose $P(x)$ into its factors as
$$P(x)=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\dots (x-a_n)^{ ^\#}$$

Now, write the equation
$$\frac 1{P(x)}=\frac{A_1}{x-a_1}+\frac{A_2}{x-a_2}\dots \frac{A_n}{x-a_n}^{ ^{\#\#}}$$
and solve for the coefficients $A_1,A_2,\dots A_n$ (either by comparing coefficients or by putting specific values).

Once you have all the values of $A_1,A_2,\dots A_n$, you can write
$$\int \frac 1{P(x)}\;\text{d}x=\int \left(\frac{A_1}{x-a_1}+\frac{A_2}{x-a_2}\dots \frac{A_n}{x-a_n}\right)\;\text{d}x$$
which you can break up into
$$\int \frac 1{P(x)}\;\text{d}x=\int\frac{A_1}{x-a_1}\;\text{d}x+\int\frac{A_2}{x-a_2}\;\text{d}x\dots +\int\frac{A_n}{x-a_n}\;\text{d}x$$
and integrate term by term. Note that since the $A_i$'s are all constants, the $\frac{A_i}{x-a_i}$ terms can be integrated very easily.

Hope that helps.

---

$\#$ Note that it was assumed that all polynomials can be factored in the mentioned form (in other words, complex roots were allowed) since I tried to sketch a general case. However, it may happen that for particular cases, other methods prove to be more helpful, and that's why textbooks teach around fifteen different tricks for different rational functions. [Here's](https://www.math24.net/integration-rational-functions) a short list of the plethora of such tricks available.

---

$\#\#$ Note that this equation assumes that your decomposition doesn't have repeated roots. If it has repeated roots, almost the same procedure is followed except this equation will have terms of all degree. In particular, if your given expression decomposes into
$$P(x)=(x-1)^2(x-2)^3$$
then, this equation will turn into
$$\frac 1{P(x)}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{C}{x-2}+\frac{D}{(x-2)^2}+\frac{E}{(x-2)^3}$$
with which you need to proceed in the same way as before. I hope I could make myself clear.

However you must remember that there's no predefined formula for computation of such integrals, all we have are different ways and methods as I mentioned in my answer

Comment: You can't always decompose P(x) into factors. Consider $P(x)=x^2+2x+3$

Comment: In this case you need to convert it into a perfect square followed by trigonometric substitution

Comment: @LalitTolani You can, if you allow complex numbers.

Comment: @LalitTolani True, but you asked for a general case, so I allowed complex numbers.

Comment: @LalitTolani please check the edit.

Comment: The strategy is good, but even over the complex numbers the partial fractions form of $1/P$ is not quite this simple: $P$ can have repeated roots, in which case $1/P$ has "pole terms" of order greater than $1$.

Comment: I agree with @AndrewD.Hwang . You did not include the case of a multiple root. Things like $$\int\frac{1}{(x-1)^2(x+2)^3}\;dx$$

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Yes, I completely forgot about them here. Looking at the type of $P(x)$ and then solving would be a better way because we can do it in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

A few things you may be interested in:

---

If the integral can be expressed as the form:
$$\int\frac{u'}{u}dx=\ln|u|+C$$

---

If the polynomial can be factored you can use [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) (there are many questions on here solved using this method)

---

Finally, [contour integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration) using [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) works well for many polynomials